# Why does react-query query not work when parameter from router.query returns undefined on refresh?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

When page is refreshed query is lost, disappears from react-query-devtools.

Before Next.js, I was using a react and react-router where I would pull a parameter from the router like this:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

It worked then. With the help of the, [Next.js Routing documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)
I have replaced `useParams` with:

```
import { usePZDetailData } from "../../hooks/usePZData";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
const PZDetail = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  const { } = usePZDetailData(id);

  return <></>;
};

export default PZDetail;
```

Does not work on refresh. I found a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72786233/why-does-my-id-i-get-from-next-js-router-query-return-undefined-on-refresh), but manually using 'refetch' from react-query in `useEffect`s doesn't seem like a good solution. How to do it then?

#### Edit

Referring to the comment, I am enclosing the rest of the code, the react-query hook. Together with the one already placed above, it forms a whole.

```
const fetchPZDetailData = (id) => {
  return axiosInstance.get(`documents/pzs/${id}`);
};

export const usePZDetailData = (id) => {
  return useQuery(["pzs", id], () => fetchPZDetailData(id), {});
};
```

#### Edit 2

I attach `PZList` page code with `<Link>` implementation

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import TableModel from "../../components/TableModel";
import { usePZSData } from "../../hooks/usePZData";
import { createColumnHelper } from "@tanstack/react-table";

type PZProps = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  entry_into_storage_date: string;
};

const index = () => {
  const { data: PZS, isLoading } = usePZSData();
  const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<PZProps>();
  const columns = [
    columnHelper.accessor("title", {
      cell: (info) => (
        <span>
          <Link
            href={`/pzs/${info.row.original.id}`}
          >{`Dokument ${info.row.original.id}`}</Link>
        </span>
      ),
      header: "Tytuł",
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("entry_into_storage_date", {
      header: "Data wprowadzenia na stan ",
    }),
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        "loading "
      ) : (
        <TableModel data={PZS?.data} columns={columns} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default index;
```

Comment: Is the issue that `id` isn't working, or is something in that `usePZDetailData` hook not working as expected? *What* is undefined? Please clarify the issue and please include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using as part of your [mcve].

Comment: I have attached more code. Hmm.. The hook works fine when navigating to the details page via <Link>. I think there is something wrong with useRouter() implementation or is it the nature of NextJs?

Comment: Can you share how you link to this page/component, and then also what exactly you are doing to produce the issue?

Comment: I've included code with the <Link> implementation. Extra info: When I click on <Link> I am redirected to the PZDetail page, in ReactQueryDevtool I see a query, the data is rendered. After refreshing the page, the query from ReactQueryDevtool disappears, in the console it pops an error - inalid query. Django server gets invalid query and then gets a second valid query.

Comment: I think that related post you found is probably what you are looking for with checking the `router.isReady` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're experiencing is due to the Next.js' [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization#how-it-works).

> If `getServerSideProps` or `getInitialProps` is present in a page, Next.js
> will switch to render the page on-demand, per-request (meaning
> [Server-Side Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering)).
>
> If the above is not the case, Next.js will **statically optimize** your
> page automatically by prerendering the page to static HTML.
>
> During prerendering, the router's `query` object will be empty since we
> do not have query information to provide during this phase. After
> hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to
> provide the route parameters in the `query` object.

Since your page doesn't have `getServerSideProps` or `getInitialProps`, Next.js statically optimizes it automatically by prerendering it to static HTML. During this process the query string is an empty object, meaning in the first render `router.query.id` will be `undefined`. The query string value is only updated after hydration, triggering another render.

---

In your case, you can work around this by [disabling the query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries) if `id` is `undefined`. You can do so by passing the `enabled` option to the `useQuery` call.

```js
export const usePZDetailData = (id) => {
    return useQuery(["pzs", id], () => fetchPZDetailData(id), {
        enabled: id
    });
};
```

This will prevent making the request to the API if `id` is not defined during first render, and will make the request once its value is known after hydration.